# How to duplicate a project Android studio, for backup

Tags: java, android, android-studio, duplicates

How to duplicate a project Android studio, for backup.

please, I want simple way.

Comment: copy the project folder to another location?

Comment: also remember to remove build, .gradle, .idea folders. they are unnecessary for backup. Using Mac simply, Command+D on project folder, Windows Cltr+C , Ctrl+P

Comment: You can also make a repo on bitbucket and push the code to save for future use. just see any youtube video how to push your code to GITHUB or BiBucket in a private repository. it's pretty simple and easy

Comment: Learn to use Git and Github/Bitbucket, etc. ASAP or you will regret it later.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is using Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V.
But it's better to use Git.